# Exporting function prototypes in ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I cant seem to export prototypes on Constructor functions I import from other parts of my codebase.

So, if I have this in `functions.js`:

```
export function Product(unprocessedItem) {
  let item = Object.assign({}, unprocessedItem);   

  return item;
}

Product.prototype.printThat = function() {
  console.log('Yo, it worked!')
}
```

And then I do this elsewhere:

```
import {Product} from '@/js/functions'

let product = new Product(result);

product.printThat();
```

`printThat()` doesnt seem to work...

Comment: You’ve returned an object, so it’s not a constructor regardless of whether you use it with `new`. (`product instanceof Product === false`.) Maybe you want `Object.assign(this, item)`? Also, use a class.

Comment: @Ry︁ That worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here actually has nothing to do with module import and export. In fact the problem is with the Product function.

```
function Product(unprocessedItem) {
  let item = Object.assign({}, unprocessedItem);   

  return item;
}

Product.prototype.printThat = function() {
  console.log('Yo, it worked!')
}

let product = new Product({ test: true });

product.printThat();
```

Doesn't work.

Because you return an item, not a Product from the Product constructor.

```
function Product(unprocessedItem) {
  Object.assign(this, unprocessedItem);
}

Product.prototype.printThat = function() {
  console.log('Yo, it worked!', this.test);
}

let product = new Product({ test: true });

product.printThat();
```

Or as a class

```
export class Product {
  constructor (unprocessedItem) {
    Object.assign(this, unprocessedItem);
  }
  printThat () {
    console.log('Yo, it worked!');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Might be nice to add, as the first line, "The problem here actually has nothing to do with module import and export. In fact the problem is with the `Product` function." Good work showing example code.

Comment: Appreciate the in depth answer. Thanks @generalhenry